# Does DirectShowLib-2005 provide support for H264 Format?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webcam, directshow, directshow.net

I want to use Logitech C-920 in my project. C920 encodes video in H264 format. I am using DirectShowLib-2005 in my project, does it provide support for H264 format , or do i need to do some tweaking?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectShowLib does not contain H.264 decoder, however if you have it installed in the system (Microsoft or third party), DirectShowLib will make it available for your application.

Comment: How can i check that H264 decoder is installed in my system? I can play H264 videos, does it mean H264 decoder is installed in my system.

Comment: The best way is to use GraphEdit from Windows SDK (alternatively, [GraphStudioNext](https://code.google.com/p/graph-studio-next/)) and open file there, then try to play it back and see if any suitable decoder jumps in.

Comment: I have open the H264 format video in GraphStudioNext. It showing me the following output. Kindly check it. [Image Link](http://postimg.org/image/le7mljzar/)

Comment: Yes, on this particular PC. On another one this codec might be missing.